# REVOKE IMPORTED PREVILEGES from role on a shared database not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any new role created on the account automatically gets access to a shared database and any attempt to REVOKE IMPORTED PRIVILEGES from the newly created role makes no change, the query to revoke access completes successfully. Notably, when IMPORTED PRIVILEGES are revoked/granted from a role on any other shared DB, it works perfectly fine.

DB: Snowflake

Comment: It sounds like you have somehow granted imported privileges for that DB to the PUBLIC role, so everyone has it

Comment: Thanks! that's the case and I wasn't expecting it

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had two other roles that were children of role `PUBLIC`. Any new role that was created automatically inherited the privileges of these two roles via the relationship to `PUBLIC`. Due to this, the command `revoke imported privileges on database <MY_DB> from role PUBLIC;` and `revoke imported privileges on database <MY_DB> from role my_role;` did not remove the privileges on the DB.

Removing the relationship between the other roles and `PUBLIC` fixed this issue for me:

```sql
revoke role my_other_role1 from role PUBLIC;
revoke role my_other_role2 from role PUBLIC;
```